# Swift core data predicate issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am trying to fetch data from core data between a range of 3 days from current date

```
let timestampToday = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timestamp >= %@ AND timestamp < %@", Int(timestampToday - Constants.THREE_DAYS), timestampToday)

            let request: NSFetchRequest<HealthKit> = HealthKit.fetchRequest()

            do{

                request.predicate = predicate
                let test = try context.fetch(request)
    }catch{ ...}
}
```

I get an without any description just (lldb) and this line highlighted in red. So it's quite evident that the predicate is the main issue here. What am I doing wrong?

[image: error image]

Comment: You can't use `%@` as a placeholder for an `Int`. Also, it would make sense to use a `TimeInterval` (Double) instead?

Comment: No need for timeInterval here I don't need much precision